# How to test a VB program which will run on a network

Tags: vb.net, networking

I am a self-taught programmer and have only delved into new areas of programming as the need arises. I have never done any network programming, everything I have written has been for a single computer. I have written a program for an old board game and it runs great. But, now I want to try to write it to run for multiple players across a local network. I have an idea of what has happen in terms of constantly checking a specified folder/file for changes. But... how do you test this without actually building/compiling the program and installing it on another computer every time you make any changes? I have tried to search various forms of what I have as the title here, but all that comes up is about testing network connections, or socket programming (would this be easier/needed) or systemfilewatcher (which may be an option too if it will run on Windows 7 and 10... but, I find nothing about testing programs to actually access the network and simulating 2 copies of the program running. Any suggestions, links, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be disappointed in the performance of a file-based network game unless reaction or refresh time is of little consequence for your "board" game. You may also need to work out potential concurrency issues (ie, someone updating a file you've just read). If you have any desire to do other games in the future you should be using sockets ([most likely UDP](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/udp-vs-tcp/) unless you have a good reason not to) to create a client server system.

As to your question, yes, you should be able to test it. You just need to run both a compiled exe and the source in VS debug mode, accessing the same folder on your drive. If you go with the socket-based option, you would use your PC's loopback address 127.0.0.1 (sometimes known as localhost), but the 2 different parts will need to communicate on different ports.

Comment: Thank you topshot... this will help immensely. In the case of this board game, only 1 player can do anything at a time... so the non-active player's programs will just be looking for a switch to be set in the file. But I do understand what you mean about the concurrency issue. Would it also work if I have 2 VS windows open and having the program open in both?

Comment: That may work. I've never tried that since it's usually a DLL I'm needing to test, which must be referenced in the other project. The concurrency could hit while polling to see whether it's your turn though I don't think locking is too big an issue for Windows in general. It would be a pretty slim chance unless you were not doing something right anyway.

Comment: If I go with the socket client-server route... would the client program be a separate program?  or a function within my game program?  Sorry for being ignorant... but as I said... I've never done any type of network programming before.

Comment: It **could** be the same program but would need to have the functionality to do both the client and server roles, depending on some setting. Someone has to run as server and everyone else would run as a client. I haven't had a need to do any network programming either other than FTP, but there is a lot of info out there. The link in my answer had lots of good info. In fact I sent it to my son since he wants to get into game programming.

Comment: **Note to both topshot and @Hari_Seldon**: While UDP is good for games since it is connectionless and handles packets, I think TCP would be a better choice in this case since it, apart from UDP, handles packet loss for you. And since this is not a very fast-paced game (like games containing moving characters, first person shooters, etc.) TCP's small overhead will most likely not be noticable.

Comment: I would agree with your assessment that TCP would be fine for this game.

Comment: Sorry, this project got put on hold for a bit. THANK YOU very much topshot and Visual Vincent.

Comment: I have tried the samples for the Server Socket Program and Client Socket Program given at http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_Server_Socket.htm and http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_Client_Socket.htm

Comment: and when I run them on the same machine... it works great... but.. when I put the client on another machine (and change the IP address accordingly)... it connects, and displays the message on the server... and shows that it is connected on the client... but when I click the button  on the form for the client, it gives me an error on the serverstrem.read lin that the specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Comment: @Hari_Seldon : You're better of asking a new question about that, then you can also include code for people to inspect.